# Ajax first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Well I am trying to use an ajax script for refreshing the content of a div.
The problem is that the first click on the href in which I call the fuction, is not responding. After the first click, it works fine.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_demo(x) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "demo.php?code=" + x,
            datatype: "html",
            success: function(data){
                $('#cart_update').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

and this is the href tag:

```
<a href="javascript::" onClick="ajax_demo('<?=$obj->code?>');">Demo</a>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The script is by chance defined after the link?

Comment: Yeah can you include some more code so we can see the scope of your function?

Comment: Your code looks okay. Change onClick to onclick and javascript:: to javascript:; please do not use inline event handlers as they are a thing of the past and they make your code look ugly and difficult to maintain.

Comment: LShetty, I did the changes you mentioned but the problem is still there. This is the only function I use. Is for refreshing a specific div pulling data from the php file.

Answer (score 1):

Not that your code is wrong, per se, but I would change it to something like:

```
<a href="#" class="myLinkClass" data-value="<?=$obj->code?>">Demo</a>
```

and the script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.myLinkClass', function() {
        var clickedEle = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "demo.php?code=" + clickedEle.attr('data-value'),
            datatype: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#cart_update').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is to make sure that the script is initialized before the call is bound, and it's easier to maintain Passing data to the click can be done in several ways of course - I just picked a "data-" attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I could use this code, but because I am builing a shopping cart, I cannot use a fixed value for href id. This code will be applied for each record, meaning mylink01, mylink02 etc.

Comment: ok, there are ways to solve that as well. I've updated the code with a new example. Just use the class for any link. You could also try your original code, but put it in $(document).ready(function() { // code })

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.myLinkClass').on('click',function() {
    var clickedEle = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "demo.php?code=" + clickedEle.attr('data-value'),
        datatype: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#cart_update').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

});

You need to use .on method in order to make it working on first click.